# Real-time notifications in laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5, notifications

What I do in my application is to use setInterval to activate the JavaScript functions and make calls to the server, to check if there are new notifications, if so, the samples. Here is the code of one of the notifications:

```
function notify_messages(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/notifyMessage",
          success: function(data){
            if(data.received == true){
              for(var i=0; i < data.messages.length; i++){
                new PNotify({
                  desktop: {
                    desktop: true,
                    title: 'New Message',
                    text: 'Have a new message from'+ data.mensajes[i] +'',
                  }
                });
                new PNotify({
                  title: '<a href="/Message/'+ data.id[i] +'" class="color-azul-link pointer">New message</a>',
                  text: 'You have a new message from <a class="pointer" href="/Message/'+ data.id[i] +'"><strong class="color-blue-link">'+ data.message[i] +'</strong></a>',
                  addclass: 'dark',
                  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-comment",
                  type: 'info',
                  delay: 10000000000,
                  styling: 'bootstrap3',
                  hide: true
                });
              }
            }
          }
          });
      }
setInterval(notify_messages, 5000);
```

On the local server works fine, when it is loaded on the production server, and if many people use it at the same time, there comes a time that makes too many requests and the server does not support it and it falls. In total, per user, it sends more or less between 8 to 9 requests with an interval of 5 seconds. If someone has some kind of solution, it would be very helpful.

Comment: If you are overloading your server, apply some sort of rate limit.

Comment: What kind of limit do you recommend?

Comment: I put 5 seconds because it seemed enough, before it was 1 second

Comment: Figure out how many requests your server can handle and work from there. I don't know what you are doing here so I can't really recommend. Ask yourself these questions to figure out what you should do. How often does a user need to be notified? If they just got a notification, when will they need to get another? How slow can I make the request before people notice? Can I queue up requests when I get overloaded? Can I combine requests/notifications?

Comment: If you are just populated a little number, such as `messages (3)`, people won't notice if it only updates once every 30 seconds (and page load). If you are doing desktop notifications, 1 per minute gets annoying *really* fast. So it all depends on your use case here.

Comment: The idea of ​​use is that you do not have to reload the page and that the notification suddenly appears